# How can I make a Link-area bigger than the Image

Tags: css, hyperlink

How can I make The Link-area like 3 px bigger than the image. I have made an audio-player with a 3px progressbar. But 3px are a bit small for a mouseclick and especially on mobiles. So how can I add like to link 3px to the top and to the bottom?

```
#gutter {
background: white;
height: 3px;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 87px;
z-index: 5;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/HP7f4/)

I made up a simplified version to demonstrate the effect.

```
<a href="#" class="link"><img class="image" src=""/></a>

a.link {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
img.image {
    width: 3px;
    height: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 0;
}
```